# Getting the text from a comboboxtext gtk3, c

Tags: c, gtk3, glade

I really searched a lot to find out the answer but didn't find anything. I created a comboboxtext  using glade3 and inserted three text values. The comboboxtext is in a form and when the user presses the ok button of the  form I want to store in const *char the text value he chose. What is the function that gets the text? I cannot see any in [GTKcombobox](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkComboBox.html#gtk-combo-box-set-id-column) .

edit : with

```
const *char d_string;
 GtkWidget *textvalue= GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builderform[0], "comboboxtext1"));
  d_string=gtk_combo_box_get_active_id(GTK_COMBO_BOX(textValue));
```

I get a segmentation fault.

Comment: Use `gtk_combo_box_set_id_column()` with the text column (once per checkbox), then `gtk_combo_box_get_active_id()` (as often as needed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
    gtk_combo_box_text_get_active_text (GtkComboBoxText *cmb);
```

Since you did not set gtk_combo_box_set_active_id(), you cannot pull the active_id. Anyway, the "id" is used if you use GtkTreeModel to fill up the combo box.